# Launch Activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I've used **BroadcastReceiver** which alarms every 10 seconds and here when it alarms it launches an activity of my app or my application.
How can I create that launch?

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
      generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?");
      String action = intent.getAction(); 
      Intent yourintent = new Intent(null, OutPut.class); 
      yourintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
      context.startActivity(yourintent);
      if (SOMEACTION.equals(action)) { 
          generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?"); 
      }
   }
```

**logcat by onclick to start activity :**

```
by onclick it returns :
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251): Process: com.manish.alarmmanager, PID: 2251
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.manish.alarmmanager/com.manish.alarmmanager.OutPut}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at com.manish.alarmmanager.OutPut.onCreate(OutPut.java:21)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
09-12 12:00:54.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2251):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please refer to my update and let me know if it works

Comment: You must post the source code of your BroadcastReceiver for us to help you.

Comment: What is on output.java line 21?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,OutPut.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Surely not, line 21 of OUTPUT.java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In side the `onRecieve()` method use

```
context.startActivity(yourintent);
```

Here **context** is passed as an argument in `onRecieve()` method.

You have to create `yourintent` as usual

But you may have to set a flag to intent as follow:

```
yourintent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Comment: the application stops!!!
Intent yourintent = new Intent(context, OutPut.class);
context.startActivity(yourintent);
OutPut.class -> is a java page (activity)

Comment: Here -> <activity android:name="com.manish.alarmmanager.OutPut" />

Comment: I used setFlag() and logcat is in my post

Comment: AlarmReceiver.java is my broadcast
but problem is this even it doesn't launch avtivity in onCreate() function let me try... maybe problem is this...

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?");

  String action = intent.getAction();

  Intent yourintent = new Intent(null, OutPut.class);

  yourintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  context.startActivity(yourintent);

  if (SOMEACTION.equals(action)) {

   generateNotification(context,"Hi how are you?");

   
  }

 }

Comment: I changed it I don't know which line was 18

Comment: your answer was true my problem was something else when I fixed it, it worked